# Can a pressure wave travel faster than a material breaks?

Tags: waves, pressure, material-science

Consider a shock wave travels through a solid (M) which causes a 4g acceleration. Down below there is an elastic spring (K1) which suppose to support the mass in case K2 will fail. K2 is a rigid body that fails under 2MG. Is it possible that the shock wave will travel to the ground before it breaks the K2 material?

I don’t have much knowledge in the subject of shock wave so excuse me if I didn’t use the right nomenclature.

Ben
[image]

Comment: by definition, if the shock waves causes an acceleration, even if minimal, K2 has to at least deform, or be pushed into the ground, how can M move and K2 stay inmutable?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by shock wave through a solid and or causes an acceleration.  Is it M that falls?  If so then forget the shock wave and just consider M moving against K1 K2.

Comment: I'll clarify: Think of the source of the wave as some kind of explosion- a pressure wave runs through the M mass (which doesn't fail), then travels to K2 and at last meet the ground. My question is, in case that the pressure wave deforms the K2 body with a force of 4Mg (green in picture), does that pressure wave will break K2 first (which is able to suffer 2Mg), or there is some kind of different mechanism that I'm not familiar with the could pass the pressure wave before the K2 material fails?